# VoiceOver ignores visible views, and speaks accessibilityLabels of hidden views

Tags: iphone, ios, accessibility, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I have UIView, that can contain one of two views. When I removeFromSuperview first view and addSubview second view I can still hear accessibiliyLabel of hidden view. And only in 1-2 seconds I can hear correct accessibiilityLabel.
I see that it is common situation when hidden state of view is changed, accessibility can be frustrated and still speak hidden views, and does not note visible views.
Also if in UITableViewCell UIButton is hidden and then hidden state changes to NO, VoiceOver ignores it like it is still hidden. Only manual implementation of UIAccessibilityContainer protocol for cell resolves mentioned problem

No Notifications can solve this issue. Even playing with accessibilityElementsHidden did not help. Struggling with this during several days

Please can you recommend is there any way to say Accessibility that hierarhy of views was changed

Comment: Can you post some code of how you add, remove, hide, unhide elements? Does isAccessibilityElement help?

Answer (score 2):

You can post a UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification or UIAccessibilityLayoutChanged to alert UIAccessibility that the view changed. Since you didn't post any code, I can only give you a generic example, e.g.:

```
UIAccessibilityPostnotification(UIAccessibilityLayoutChanged,accessibilityelement)
```

...where "accessibilityelement" would be a button or text field or other accessibility element that VoiceOver switches to next.

Reference: [UIKIt Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html)

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into this myself with a third party side menu library and had to use accessibilityElementsHidden to fix it. I first tried leveraging the accessibilityViewIsModal property, but that only works on sibling views.

```c
#pragma mark - IIViewDeckControllerDelegate

- (void)viewDeckController:(IIViewDeckController *)viewDeckController didOpenViewSide:(IIViewDeckSide)viewDeckSide animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (viewDeckSide == IIViewDeckLeftSide) {
        [self.topViewController.view endEditing:YES];
        self.viewDeckController.leftController.view.accessibilityElementsHidden = NO;
    }
}

- (void)viewDeckController:(IIViewDeckController *)viewDeckController didCloseViewSide:(IIViewDeckSide)viewDeckSide animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.viewDeckController.leftController.view.accessibilityElementsHidden = YES;
}
```